# Update same table after Insert trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, triggers, oracle11g

I am working on a product in which I have to send SMS to concerned person when someone waits for more than 15 minutes for being served.

For that I have written a procedure that watches a table and stores `CUST_ID, CUST_CATEGORY, DURATION` in a separate table when the `Duration` exceeds 15. The table structure of this table is:

**Some_Table**

`CUST_ID          CUST_CATEGORY          DURATION         SMS_STATUS`

I wrote a trigger as:

**Trigger**

```
create or replace trigger kiosk_sms_trg 
after insert on Some_Table 
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
BEGIN 
SMS_Proc@My_Server; --Procudure that generates SMS
update Some_Table set status = 'Y' where id = (select max(id) id  from Some_Table where status = 'N'); --Update Table that SMS has been sent
select 'Y' into :new.status from dual;
END;
```

But it creates Mutation Problem. How do I resolve it? Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm using Oracle 11G.

Comment: Get rid of this line `referencing new as new old as old` you don't use it.

Comment: I have a feeling this is not right. `SMS_Proc@My_Server;` should update that table.

Comment: I think OP needs to do a bit of reading on triggers before using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that UPDATE is allowed on SOME_TABLE as it is currently mutating.

Why not place it right after the INSERT statement which fired the trigger in the first place?.

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE ...
update Some_Table set status = 'Y' where id = (select max(id) id  from Some_Table where status = 'N'); --Update Table that SMS has been sent
```

I guess this would be the right approach considering you aren't doing anything row specific in that UPDATE.

As I mentioned in the comment, Is there any particular use for this last statement in the `AFTER INSERT` trigger? It does have meaning in the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

```
select 'Y' into :new.status from dual;
```

Comment: The Status col will be by default N, when text has been sent, only then it needs to be Y.

Comment: I see that you are using an "AFTER INSERT" trigger. Shouldn't that be an "BEFORE INSERT" trigger for this to happen?

Comment: If I use Before Insert, the record ID of the previous customer gets picked.

Comment: @IngilaEjaz I couldn't understand you. Please explain this scenario by editing / adding to your question.

Comment: @Ingila In a _before trigger_, the `id` is either accessible from `:new.id` (if it was set before the trigger has fired) -- or, if you need to, you might generate it from a sequence directly from that trigger. No need for sub-optimal solutions like `select max(id) ...` to get that value.

Comment: @toddlermenot yes that's exectly what I did :) Updated the table in the procedure after the trigger was fired.. Thanks :)

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks for the suggestion but the sequence is reset everyday. So I don't think that would be a fine approach.. However, the problem is resolved :) Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Ingila If you solved your issue yourself, please feel free to post your own answer and self-accept it. This will mark the issue as resolved -- and it will help anyone coming to this question from a search on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the same table in Row-Level `AFTER Trigger`.

Change your Row-Level `AFTER INSERT` trigger to row-level `BFEORE INSERT` trigger.

But you UPDATE stmt inside the trigger will not effect the new record being inserted.

Wonder how it can be done, this is tricky.